# add favicons into a bootstrap built website?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, favicon

This is my very first bootstrap website. I've made 1000 in plain html, css, etc. This is normally the code that I put in the '' section on every html page.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/android-chrome-192x192.png" sizes="192x192">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16">
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/mstile-144x144.png">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

Here is my [newest site in bootstrap](http://stnickporticons.com/)
Now my bootstrap pages are all .php files.

The folder of the site consists of the following folders:

```
 1. CSS
 2. Fonts
 3. Images
 4. Less
 5. JS
```

The root drive has 38 php pages and a prepros.cfg files. I've done a lot of google searching but can't find out how and where to place the favivon code so that when you view the church site that you see the favicon.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't understand, the favicon is appearing? What device/browser are you using?

Comment: Do you have a php file you include on every page?

Comment: @mulquin I see the generic 32 x 32 .ico file, which is in the root of the drive.

Comment: @Mathieu de Lorimier I have 34 php pages in the site.

Comment: Ok, the idea would be to put everything that is "header" in a seprate file and include that in every page. Same goes with the footer stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i believe if you are using php you must have exported the header portion to a single php file which you are calling via include or require in your every file
just copy and paste the header portion to that file

if you have just renamed all your html files to php and have not done any change I believe it will work as before

Comment: No this site was made all in php, there was no conversion from html. I have a header php, footer php, functions php, parseContactForm php, right-sidebar php and a prepros.cfg

Comment: you needto paste all your link tags in header.php file just once

Comment: thank you @ahhmarr  learning the bootstrap system is taking me a bit to wrap my head around